# How to do swagger server integration without swagger annotation?

Tags: annotations, jax-rs, swagger

I am able to integrate CXF jax-rs with swagger annotation(@Api, @ApiOperation, @ApiResponses, @ApiParam)

But I would like to integrate without @Api, @ApiOperation, @ApiResponses, @ApiParam.
I have looked at following code - 
https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-jaxrs-no-annotations

I am not able to understand how swagger server integrates with jax-rs / scans jax-rs annotations without swagger annotations.

Comment: Have you tried using the JSON instead of annotations?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - the sample is present in 1.4 branch - [java-jaxrs-no-annotations sample](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/697a4bdb4c1d99e27ff863c4db7304a073b36945/samples/java-jaxrs-no-annotations)

Also, mind the drawbacks of this approach - you can found them in the [original ticket for Allow scanning of non-annotated JAX-RS Resources](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/489)

In short - the [Bootstrap servlet](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/697a4bdb4c1d99e27ff863c4db7304a073b36945/samples/java-jaxrs-no-annotations/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/Bootstrap.java) uses the SwaggerConfig to set the Api information and the authorization scopes, while the real scanning of the JAX-RS annotations is configured in the [web.xml](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/697a4bdb4c1d99e27ff863c4db7304a073b36945/samples/java-jaxrs-no-annotations/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) - by using swagger specific configuration classes like com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig.

In order to understand these things better you can take a look at the [integrating swagger into JAX-RS sample](http://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/12/14/integrating-swagger-into-jax-rs-with-java-ee-6-specification/) which illustrates how these configurations can be done programatically, without a web.xml

Comment: Does this mean this feature is not available in the release version?

Comment: I am not really sure, but I assume so. You can contact the Swagger developers and share the knowledge here.